# Can't add foreign key constraints on Laravel5.5

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.5

i created several tables :

**KEYNEEDS TABLE :**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('keyneeds', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->integer('segment_id')->index('FK_KN_SEGMENT');
        $table->integer('design_id')->index('FK_KEYNEEDS_DESIGN');
        $table->integer('admin_id')->index('FK_KN_ADMIN');
        $table->string('kntextcolor', 191)->nullable();
        $table->string('kntextcolorhover', 191)->nullable();
        $table->string('knbgcolor', 191)->nullable();
        $table->string('knbgcolorhover', 191)->nullable();
        $table->string('knhvize', 191)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}
```

**DESIGNS TABLE :**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('designs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->string('design', 191)->nullable();
    });
}
```

**I also added foreign key constraints**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('keyneeds', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->foreign('design_id', 'FK_KEYNEEDS_DESIGN')->references('id')->on('designs')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
        $table->foreign('admin_id', 'FK_KN_ADMIN')->references('id')->on('admins')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
        $table->foreign('segment_id', 'FK_KN_SEGMENT')->references('id')->on('segments')->onUpdate('RESTRICT')->onDelete('RESTRICT');
    });
}
```

i have this SQL error when i try to migrate the database:

```
Can not add external index constraints (SQL: alter table `keyneeds` add constraint` FK_KEYNEEDS_DESIGN` foreign key (`design_id`) references`
```

igns`(`id`) on delete RESTRICT on update RESTRICT)

Comment: try to add unsigned index into table(KEYNEEDS TABLE):
```$table->integer('segment_id')-> unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('design_id')-> unsigned()->index();```

Comment: i tried but it's not working ... i also tried $table->integer('design_id',11)-> unsigned()->index()

Comment: Is `designs` also an `InnoDB` table?

Comment: it was meant to be an `InnoDB` table ... i just forgot  `$table->engine = 'InnoDB';`

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer and accept it? This shows other users that the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given by Jonas Staudenmeir :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('designs', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->integer('id', true);
        $table->string('design', 191)->nullable();
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
    });
}
```